# how do i use findone in loopback.js

Tags: loopbackjs

I have several objects in model. I want to find by

`"user":"restlessankur@gmail.com"`

How do i do this in loopback.js?

I tried findOne and I input

`{"user": "restlessankur@gmail.com"}`

I see result containing  `user:restlessankur@gmail.com`

But, if i filter it by `user:meghanetpulse7@gmail.com`

even then, I get `"user":"restlessankur@gmail.com"` as result.

So, I have 2 questions

1) Is `findOne` correct method for my scenerio?

2) If yes, than what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your model is `User`:

```js
User.findOne({where: {email: 'restlessankur@gmail.com'}}, (err, user) => {
  if (err || !user) {
    console.log('Something went wrong')
  } else {
    // do something with the user object
  }
})
```

Comment: This is exactly the way you find one object using Loopback ORM. https://apidocs.loopback.io/loopback/#persistedmodel-findone. I've been working on a big Loopback project for a while, I wouldn't have answered otherwise. Why did you downvoted my answer if you didn't even try the code above?

Comment: I have not downvoted. Why would I downvote someone who is helping me out. My question is also downvoted twice :)

Comment: By the way, was that useful? Did you try it?

Comment: yes, it worked flawlessly. Can i send you private message to learn more about loopback?

Comment: Sure, go ahead.

Comment: How do i do that? email id?

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot understand your question. Please provide a scenario with better explanation and more details.

Comment: My question is solved . Thanks. I am just saying if i need future help, can i contact you personally?

Comment: Twitter: @antoniotrapani